# Can I determine `IsDevelopment` from `IWebJobsBuilder`

Tags: asp.net-core, startup, development-environment, environment, azure-function-app

Very much an XY problem, but I'm interested in the underlying answer too.
See bottom for XY context.

---

I'm in a .NET Core 3 AzureFunctions (v3) App project.
This code makes my question fairly clear, I think:

```cs
namespace MyProj.Functions
{
    internal class CustomStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var isDevelopment = true; //Can I correctly populate this, such that it's true only for local Dev?
            if(isDevelopment)
            {
                // Do stuff I wouldn't want to do in Prod, or on CI...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***XY Context:***

*I have set up Swagger/Swashbuckle for my Function, and ideally I want it to auto-open the swagger page when I start the Function, locally.*

*On an API project this is trivial to do in Project Properties, but a Functions csproj doesn't have the option to start a web page "onDebug"; that whole page of project Properties is greyed out.*

*The above is the context in which I'm calling `builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` and I've added a call to  `Diagnostics.Process` to start a webpage during Startup. This works just fine for me.*
*I've currently got that behind a `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` flag, but I'd like it to be more constrained if possible. Definitely open to other solutions, but I haven't been able to find any so ...*

Answer (score 0):

While I am not completely sure that it is possible in azure functions I think that setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT application setting as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings should allow you to get whether the environment is set as production or development by injecting a IHostEnvironment dependency and checking

```
.IsDevelopment()
```

on the injected dependency.